# mount: you must specify the filesystem type

Tags: linux, mount, qemu, linaro

I was trying to execute qemu while following the qemu/linaro tutorial,
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Developer_guide/Virtual_ARM_Linux_environment

I was executing the command,

> sudo mount -o loop,offset=106496 -t auto vexpress.img /mnt/tmp
>
> mount: you must specify the filesystem type

so i did fdisk on the img file and got the following,

> Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
>
> vexpress.img1   *          63      106494       53216    e  W95 FAT16 (LBA)
>
> vexpress.img2          106496     6291455     3092480   83 Linux

The filesystem is Linux according to the fdisk command. But I get error,

> sudo mount -o loop,offset=106496 -t Linux vexpress.img /mnt/tmp
>
> mount: unknown filesystem type 'Linux'

Kindly help.

Comment: 83, "Linux" is probably ext2 or ext3 (I forget which one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You correctly decide to mount the particular partition by specifying its offset but the offset parameter is in bytes and `fdisk` shows the offset in blocks (the block size is shown before the partition list --- usually 512). For the block size 512 the command would be:

```
sudo mount -o loop,offset=$((106496*512)) -t auto vexpress.img /mnt/tmp
```

If the automatic file system type detection does not still work there is another problem. `Linux` is not really a file system type. In the partition table it is a collective type used for multiple possible particular file systems. For `mount` you must specify the particular file system. In Linux you can list the supported ones by `cat /proc/filesystems`.